# Unity Abstract class with parameter

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, new-operator, abstract

I have not been able to figure out the purpose of the "new()" word in this code. I appreciate any insight and help understanding it. What is the meaning/functionality of "new()"  in this piece of code?

```
 public abstract class GameManagerBase<TGameManager, TDataStore> : PersistentSingleton<TGameManager>
    where TDataStore : GameDataStoreBase, new()
    where TGameManager : GameManagerBase<TGameManager, TDataStore>

 public abstract class GameDataStoreBase : IDataStore
{
    public float masterVolume = 1;

    public float sfxVolume = 1;

    public float musicVolume = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called just before we save
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void PreSave();

    /// <summary>
    /// Called just after load
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void PostLoad();
}
```

Comment: It's a generic type constraint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not Unity3d specific but general `c#`.

In this case [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) is a **type constraint** for the generic type parameter `TDataStore`. Meaning when you actually implement

```
public class Example : GameManagerBase<SomeManager, SomeStore> { ... }
```

the type `SomeStore` has to fulfill whatever constraints are given for the `TDataStore` - which can be a certain base class, interfaces and some special constraints.

---

The [`new()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) is such a special constraint.

It means that `TDataStore` has to be a type that provides a **public parameter-less constructor**. This is required for being able to create instances of the given type (without using ugly Reflection).